# How should I fix the problem of two part surname taken as middle name by google scholar?

Tags: publications, citations, google-scholar, personal-name, indexing

I recently published my [first paper in a conference proceedings (CogSci2020)](https://cognitivesciencesociety.org/cogsci20/papers/0183/). Before submitting I was struggling how to give my name. My name is:

- First: [Alireza]
- Last: [Mahmoudi Kamelabad]

The two words for the last name are both my last name. First I was thinking to get rid of Mahmoudi and publish with **Alireza Kamelabad** since Kamelabad is pretty rare and except my uncle and a relative who publish there are no Kamelabads in the world. But I thought maybe it is better to give my full name. So I did and now that the paper is appeared in [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=11647009302339698289&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) it considers **Mahmoudi** as a middle name and for citation makes it *AM Kamelabad* instead of *A Mahmoudi Kamelabad*.

I have set up my Google Scholar account and tried to fix my name by there but it does not happen. Also the citation that Google Scholar shows is wrong in general in terms of format.
My question is how can I fix that? Is there any way I could specify in google scholar that [Mahmoudi Kamleabad] is a chunk and not separable?

Thank you.

Comment: Would you accept hyphenating "Mahmoudi Kamelabad" as a fix?

Comment: Since you say you would consider shortening to "Alireza Kamelabad", is it important to you that "Mahmoudi" *not* be treated as a middle name? That is, you'd rather drop it entirely rather than have it mistaken as a middle name? Of course naming conventions vary by culture, but I know people who have taken one parent's surname as a middle name and the other as an official surname (and this is in the US, where traditionally children take the father's surname, or the mother's if they are a single parent; this tradition has been shifting in some cases lately, though).

Comment: Let me apologize on behalf of academia that you have to deal with this. You should be able to just use your own name in your own preferred format without hassle, regardless of your culture.

Answer (score 5):

Google crawled your data from somewhere, I suspect that source gave Google the wrong data. E.g., perhaps a bibtex listing is wrong. So, to fix the problem, you could fix the source.

Taking *Mahmoudi* as the middle name in *Alireza Mahmoudi Kamelabad* is a standard reading. To avoid that reading, you could use *Alireza Mahmoudi-Kamelabad* in the future.

Comment: Specifically in BibTeX files, you can make this work by writing 'Alireza {Mahmoudi Kamelebad}' - that will tell BibTeX, and any system that properly parses BibTeX, that 'Mahmoudi Kamelebad' is an indivisible chunk. However, Google may not recognize that, or may override with information from another incorrect in source.

Answer (score 0):

In your Google Scholar profile page you can edit the citation by clicking on the name of the article. Just move your first surname to after the comma, together with your second one. At the very least it should help Google to catch on.